# what is the complexity of harmonic series

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I try to evaluate the complexity of the following pseudo code:

```
S=0;
for (i=1; i<n; i++)
  for (j=0; j<n; j+=i)
    S=S+1;
```

At first it seems pretty straight forward:

> First for loop - $n$
>
> and what about the second one?
> $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil+1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$
>
> so the answer should be something like : $n+n-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$
>
> now I think that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{k}$ is a harmonic series so $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{k}=O(nlog(n))$ (**this is only the harmoic part without the rest** is it correct??)
>
> But what can I do if it is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$?

Please help me figure it out.

Comment: You have a mistake in your computation. the result is $O(n\log(n))$. You've missed $n$.

Comment: Suppose the $j$ loop were not there at all, or were `for (j = 0; j < 1; j++)`. Then then answer would be $\Theta(n)$. So by doing MORE work, there's no way you get $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Also, for complexity case you can ignore the ceil function.

Comment: @OmG you mean that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$ is $O(nlog(n))$?

Comment: @misha312 yes, it is.

Comment: @OmG why can I ignore the ceil function? isn't for any $n$ element $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil \gt  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{k}$

Comment: Yes. but at most the difference between each item is $1$ and you can ignore it for complexity case. it means it does not change the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your computation. the result is $O(n\log(n))$. You've missed $n$ in your final result.

Also, for the complexity case you can ignore the ceil function. Because at most the difference between each item $\lceil \frac{n}{k}\rceil$ and $\frac{n}{k}$ is $1$ , then you can ignore it for the complexity case. it means it does not change the complexity, as it would be $O(n\log(n) + n) = O(n\log(n))$.